# Размещение DIV в ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, css

Здравствуйте. 
Пишу сайт на asp.net c# .Подскажите ,как сделать чтобы элемент div выводился поверх других элементов( он был на переднем фоне, а остальные элементы страницы на заднем) ?
Буду рад примерам или ссылкам на то, где об этом можно почитать .
Спасибо.

Comment: а при чем тут ASP.NET? Вне зависимости от технологии юзайте css и/или js, в частности, z-index - они не зависят от фреймворков.

Comment: @DreamChild , Спасибо, буду разбираться с css

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
.megastyle {
            position: absolute;
        }
```

position: absolute .

Comment: эмм..а как это относится к вашему вопросу? даже если этим вы достигаете перекрытия одного элемента другим, position absolute предназначено для других целей, и использовать его с такой целью вряд ли правильно

Comment: @DreamChild .С css я до этого не работал. Поясните  пожалуйста ,почему не правильно. Нужный элемент оказывается на переднем фоне, осталось только разобраться с тем,  как затемнить остальные , и всё будет работать.